# Tango_Ros_Streamer record data?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to record data from Tango with Tango Ros Streamer and save them into a bag by command: rosbag record -a
When i visualize sequence of image in this bag, i realize the frame rate is extremely slow. Do you have any idea to modify or fix frame rate with this application?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266039/tango_ros_streamer-record-data???/) by [trinamntn08](https://answers.ros.org/users/30882/trinamntn08/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the [documentation for tango_ros_streamer](http://wiki.ros.org/tango_ros_streamer), I see that it outputs a lot of data, including some high-bandwidth topics like point clouds and images. When you are recording all of the ROS messages with `rosbag record -a`, you may be recording data faster than your hard drive can store it, causing `rosbag record` to drop messages. There are a few ways you could solve that problem:

- If you don't need all of the data (you only mention looking at the images), you can specify only those topics to record.
- If you're recording to a platter hard drive, you could try switching to a solid state drive.
- You might also be able to improve recording performance by increasing the buffer size. For example, `rosbag record -a --buffersize=1024` quadruples the message buffer during recording. For more information, see the [rosbag command line documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline).

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0